# When using fetchMore with useQuery previous data is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, apollo-client

I use fetchMore function for pagination with useQuery hook. Previous data is always undefined in the updateQuery
[image: in here]

[image: it is my useQuery hook]

[image: my client setting]

Answer (score 0):

You should define a [merge strategy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api/#improving-the-merge-function) on your cache:

```
const cache = new InMemoryCache({
  typePolicies: {
    Query: {
      fields: {
        viewer: {
          keyArgs: [],
          merge(existing, incoming, { args: { offset = 0 }}) {
            // Slicing is necessary because the existing data is
            // immutable, and frozen in development.
            const merged = existing ? existing.slice(0) : [];
            for (let i = 0; i < incoming.length; ++i) {
              merged[offset + i] = incoming[i];
            }
            return merged;
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

replace viewer with whatever query you are working with.